# Enviar 2 Array com json_encode com comando While PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Não sei e melhor forma de explicar mas vamos lá.

Eu tenho um game com sistema de luta por .js a ideia atual é adicionar CD(Tempo de Recarga) nas skills.
[image: Skill em Recarga]

Quando eu usar outra Skill a anterior sai de CD e coloca a nova em CD.
[image: Nova Skill em recarga]

Se o CD for 1 ele funciona porque o .JS pega uma skill em CD por vez, POREM ai vem a questão e se tiver duas em CD? Como o CD é 1 acaba dando certo mas quando aumento ele...
[image: Skill CD em 10]
A Skill em CD de 1 Sai do CD e de 10 Entra, porem quando eu clicar em outra que tenha 1 de CD para usa-la, a skill em 10 deveria ir para 9 8 7 até em fim sair do CD, mas oque acontece é o seguinte:
[image: Duas em CD]
A nova entra em CD mas a antiga não é alterada, no console.log
[image: Log]
Aqui ela enviou para a Skill "Soco" sair do CD, ou seja ela envia apenas 1 vez esse "t_desblock_o".

arquivo.php
[image: arquivo.php]
Aqui a ideia é simples, ele ordena em ID para tirar a CD da ultima skill colocada e funcionar no 1 em 1, porque se não estiver assim ele deixa todas as outras skills funcionarem normal enquanto a de 10 não chegar a 0.
batalha.js
[image: batalha.js]
Esse é o codigo do JS que recebe o valor e então faz a mudança em jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não consegui enviar dois valores repetidos mas fui capaz de enviar novos valores e receber eles dentro do .js da seguinte forma

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

com $n = $n+1 ele gera varios array enviando eles para o .js a gambiarra foi feita lá dentro... como não conseguia fazer a Array dentro do .js escalar com o While eu fiz varias if
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]